# Не работает classList.add при клике на дочерний элемент

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть примерно такой код:

```js
const descr = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio')

for (let openAndClose of descr) {

  const gallery = openAndClose.children[2] //Список
  const closeButton = openAndClose.children[2].children[0].children[0] //Кнопка "Х"

  const openGallery = () => gallery.classList.remove("hidden")
  const closeGallery = () => {
    gallery.classList.add("hidden");
    console.log('click')
  }

  openAndClose.addEventListener('click', openGallery)
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', closeGallery)

  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape" && !gallery.classList.contains("hidden")) closeGallery()
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="op-portf">
    <h2>ProgectName</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="descr">
    <h3>site</h3>
    <p>description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pictures hidden">
    <div class="gallery-place">
      <button class="close-pic">X</button>
      <div class="pictures-collection">
        <p>pic1</p>
        <p>pic2</p>
        <p>pic3</p>
        <p>pic4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="op-portf">
    <h2>ProgectName</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="descr">
    <h3>site</h3>
    <p>description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pictures hidden">
    <div class="gallery-place">
      <button class="close-pic">X</button>
      <div class="pictures-collection">
        <p>pic1</p>
        <p>pic2</p>
        <p>pic3</p>
        <p>pic4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="op-portf">
    <h2>ProgectName</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="descr">
    <h3>site</h3>
    <p>description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pictures hidden">
    <div class="gallery-place">
      <button class="close-pic">X</button>
      <div class="pictures-collection">
        <p>pic1</p>
        <p>pic2</p>
        <p>pic3</p>
        <p>pic4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Суть такова: при клике на каждый `<div class="portfolio">` открывается некий уникальный список (функция openGallery). Соответственно при клике на кнопку "Х" в этом списке он должен закрываться (функция closeGallery). Но почему-то это не работает, список не закрывается. Ошибок никаких не выдаёт и если в функцию добавить какой-нибудь console.log, он выведется. Причём при добавлении этой функции в событие нажатия клавиши "Escape", список закроется. Помогите разобраться в чём дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас срабатывает всплытие события. Поэтому при клике на крестик, события клика всплывает до корневого элемента, при клике на который должна открываться галерея. Как следствие она снова открывается и убирается класс. Надо использовать `stopPropagation`;

```js
const descr = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio')
    
    for (let openAndClose of descr) { 
        let  gallery = openAndClose.children[2]//Список
        let closeButton = openAndClose.children[2].children[0].children[0]//Кнопка "Х"

        const openGallery = () => gallery.classList.remove("hidden")
        const closeGallery = (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation(); // <-- Убираем дальнейшую передачу текущего события.
            gallery.classList.add("hidden"); 
        }

    openAndClose.addEventListener('click', openGallery)
    closeButton.addEventListener('click', closeGallery) 

    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape" && !gallery.classList.contains("hidden")) closeGallery()})
}
```

```css
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
        <div class="op-portf">
            <h2>ProgectName</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="descr">
            <h3>site</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pictures hidden">
            <div class = "gallery-place">
                <button class="close-pic">X</button>
                <div class="pictures-collection">
                    <p>pic1</p>
                    <p>pic2</p>
                    <p>pic3</p>
                    <p>pic4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>         
    </div>

<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="op-portf">
        <h2>ProgectName</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="descr">
        <h3>site</h3>
        <p>description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pictures hidden">
        <div class = "gallery-place">
            <button class="close-pic">X</button>
            <div class="pictures-collection">
                <p>pic1</p>
                <p>pic2</p>
                <p>pic3</p>
                <p>pic4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>         
</div>

<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="op-portf">
        <h2>ProgectName</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="descr">
        <h3>site</h3>
        <p>description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pictures hidden">
        <div class = "gallery-place">
            <button class="close-pic">X</button>
            <div class="pictures-collection">
                <p>pic1</p>
                <p>pic2</p>
                <p>pic3</p>
                <p>pic4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>         
</div>
```